# Print Biórn instead of BiÃ³rn from js object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think I am lacking in the correct vocabulary to be able to state this question correctly. But I have searched everything I can think of, including "javascript object ascii", "javascript object to unicode", but the answer I'm looking for just won't show.

My problem is that I have a JavaScript object that looks like this:

```
{
    Book: 'Teacup',
    Type: 'Secondary',
    Name: 'Biórn',
    Age: '257',
    Race: 'Dwarf',
    Gender: 'Male'
}
```

and when I print it out using the following function:

```
for (var prop in item) { // item is my object
    var lineItem = $('<td/>');
    lineItem.text(item[prop]);
    lineItems.push(lineItem);
};
```

it looks like this:
*Teacup Secondary BiÃ³rn 257 Dwarf Male*

How do I fix it?

Comment: Where does your JS object come from? It might simply be an issue of storing it using the right character encoding (should be UTF-8.)

Comment: It's in a .js file. How do I check?

Comment: Open it in an editor such as NotePad++, check what file encoding it reports – and convert it to UTF-8, if it is something else.

Comment: Have you checked your HTML charset is UTF-8?

Comment: @Forcefield how do I do that?

Comment: I opened the document in Notepad++ and in the lower right hand corner it says UTF-8. But then I opened it in notepad and chose "save as" and chose UTF-8, when I then opened it in Notepad++ again it says UTF-8-BOM and it works correctly! What's the difference?

Comment: Seems you solved it, but HTML charset you set manually using meta tags on the head of the HTML. See here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Comment: @Forcefield Aha, ok, that seems like a much better solution since I don't want to have to keep resaveing my files all of the time. Would you like to post it as an answer, or should I do it myself?

Comment: You could post it I don't mind ;)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Forcefield Actually, the meta tags _document_ the encoding. The actual encoding is what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The character Ã followed by some other strange character is a typical indication that you file has UTF-8 encoding but is interpreted as something else, often latin-1 (also known as ISO-8859-1). In UTF-8, some characters occupy more than one byte. In this case, two bytes represent the character ó in UTF-8 but represents the two characters Ã³ in latin-1.

Notepad++ is smart enough to identify the correct encoding, probably by scanning a portion of the file for UTF-8 characters. But the browser doesn't seem to be able to determine the correct encoding unless the file contains a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

As mentioned in the comments, you can set the encoding explicitly with the [HTML meta tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that solved this for me. I thought this had to do with the way that javascript fetched the data from the object, but as @CBroe pointed out, it had to do with the encoding of my datafile.

Therefore my first solution was to resave the file that contained the object, making sure that it was in UTF-8 format. I did this by opening it in notepad, pressing "save as", and choosing "UTF-8" in the dropdown next to "Encoding".

This solved the problem, but it also meant that I would have to do this for each file that I wanted to create. @Forcefield suggested that I checked the charset of my HTML-page as described in this link: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp.

In short, it says that the charset of an HTML-page is set by using a meta tag inside the page's `<head>`-tag.

For HTML 4:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

and for HTML 5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Using this option worked for me as well.

This should porbably be basic knowledge for any web-developer, but it's been a while since I created a page from scratch and finding this simple answer was not as easy as it maybe should have been. I hope this helps somebody else as well.